# How do I unit test requests against SSL-only Web Api Controller?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, ssl, asp.net-web-api2, owin

I have a unit test which uses the OWIN `TestServer` class to host my Web Api `ApiController` classes for testing.

I first wrote the unit test when the REST API did not have the HTTPS (SSL) requirement baked into the `Controller` itself.

My unit test looked something like this:

```
[TestMethod]
[TestCategory("Unit")]
public async Task Test_MyMethod()
{
    using (var server = TestServer.Create<TestStartup>())
    {
        //Arrange
        var jsonBody = new JsonMyRequestObject();
        var request = server.CreateRequest("/api/v1/MyMethod")
            .And(x => x.Method = HttpMethod.Post)
            .And(x => x.Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonBody), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));

        //Act
        var response = await request.PostAsync();
        var jsonResponse =
            JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonMyResponseObject>(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());

        //Assert
        Assert.IsTrue(response.IsSuccessStatusCode);
    }

}
```

Now that I've applied the attribute to enforce HTTPS, my unit test fails.

How do I fix my test so that, all things being equal, the test passes again?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To fix this unit test, you need to change the base address for the `TestServer`.

Once the server has been created set the `BaseAddress` property on the created object to use an "https" address. Remember the default `BaseAddress` value is `http://localhost`.

In which case, you can use `https://localhost`.

The changed unit test would look as follows:

```
[TestMethod]
[TestCategory("Unit")]
public async Task Test_MyMethod()
{
    using (var server = TestServer.Create<TestStartup>())
    {
        //Arrange
        server.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost");
        var jsonBody = new JsonMyRequestObject();
        var request = server.CreateRequest("/api/v1/MyMethod")
            .And(x => x.Method = HttpMethod.Post)
            .And(x => x.Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonBody), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));

        //Act
        var response = await request.PostAsync();
        var jsonResponse =
            JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonMyResponseObject>(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());

        //Assert
        Assert.IsTrue(response.IsSuccessStatusCode);
    }

}
```